# Difference between "Better than" and "More than"

Tags: comparisons

Is it always possible to use "better than" and "more than" interchangeably?

> Many users prefer the look and feel of A **better than** B.
>   Many users prefer the look and feel of A **more than** B.

Edit: The above examples are quoted from [here](http://www.tomshardware.com/reviews/fedora-16-gnome-3-review,3155-16.html):

> Many users prefer the look and feel of GNOME 2 better than GNOME 3.
>   Thankfully, a fellow by the name of Ron Yorston already created an
>   extension pack that essentially transforms GNOME 3 into a logical
>   upgrade of GNOME 2, instead of the complete departure that GNOME Shell
>   is by default.

Comment: No it's not. For example: 7 is *not* better than 5.

Comment: except if they are up votes

Comment: Related: [“Like something more” or “like something better”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4988/like-something-more-or-like-something-better)

Comment: In your example, the use of both *prefer* and *better* is incorrect. You just *prefer* something, *over* or *to* some other thing.

Comment: @Jim: But you can say "It's better than five miles to the lake."

Comment: You're taking the phrase ["more is better"](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=more+is+better&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) much too literally. It's not a tautology.

Comment: @Robusto: ...and let the listener figure out if that is farther or nearer. :-)  (at least I'm not aware of this idiom.)

Comment: @Kris: For what it's worth, I _have_ heard that phraseology before. (In fact, I think I've heard it better 'n a dozen times or so – although almost always as informal speech.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is qualitative versus quantitative. When you refer to higher quality, you say *better* and when you mean a bigger quantity, you say *more*.
In a casual use, when detail really doesn't matter, and  you only mean one over another in a general sense, you may use either word in most contexts.

In the given context, *prefer* takes ***over*** instead:
"Many users prefer the look and feel of A **over** B."

Comment: This answer would be better with examples

Answer (score 2):

Your insertion of the word "always" in your question is bound to generate some dissent.

There are plenty of uses of the terms *more than* and *better than* where the two would not be interchangeable.  Consider:

> On the violin, Roger performs *better* than Felix.
>   When it comes to keyboard
>   layouts, some purists believe DVORAK is *better* than QWERTY.
>   Manchester played *better* than Liverpool last night, but Liverpool
>   still won the game.
>   Such a nice evening!  The weather doesn't get
>   any *better* than this.
>   That garage band is sounding much *better*
>   than they did last year – thank goodness!
>
> Listen, Robert, I've had *more* than enough of your shenanigans!
>   The cost of gasoline is *more* than it was last year.
>   In some
>   Olympic events, strength matters *more* than speed.
>   Some rules of
>   geometry get very complicated in *more* than three dimensions.
>   *More* than anything else, communication is the key to a happy marriage.

Clearly, the use of *more than* and *better than* are **not** interchangeable in those examples.  This is unsurprising, as *more* is not always the same as *better*.  (At the dinner table, for example, *more* food and *better* food are two very different things).

Still, there are some instances where either one could be used, particularly when we are talking about preferences:

> Most children like vanilla ice cream *more than* chocolate.
>   No!  I disagree!  Most kids like chocolate *better than* vanilla.

Answer (score 1):

"Better" refers to quality.
"More" refers to quantity.

It is seldom the case that you can have something be greater in quality and quantity referring to the same property. "Like" is one of those rare cases, where "I like this better" and "I like it more" mean the same thing. The confusion is due to your using of "prefer" in place of "like", where "prefer" does not have this same property of usage.

As other answers already pointed out, you would have to construct your sentences as "prefer X over Y" or "prefer X to Y", since you cannot "prefer X more than Y" ("prefer" already means exactly that, "to like something better than another").

It is also true that Gnome 2 was (and still is) better than Gnome shell. Shame the upgrade was forced on us.

Answer (score 0):

In your example, neither works. "prefer" is followed by a "to".

> Many users prefer the look and feel of A to B.

Or to be clearer,

> Many users prefer the look and feel of A to that of B.

Comment: That's a bit too pushy for my tastes. *Prefer* can also take *over*, *rather than*, *above*, and *before*. [There's a question for that.](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/1771/300)

Answer (score 0):

One use where they are definitely not interchangeable is

> I have 10 apples more than you.

Answer (score 0):

The "better" in the first example is not required due to the use of "prefer".

"over" would be preferable still to indicate that A ranks higher than B;

Many users prefer the look and feel of A **over** B.