Why "I like cats very much" and "I like cats better"?
This may be a duplicate, but I can't find it.
In a non-comparative sentence, one says "I like cats very much" (I'm not sure if "very" can be omitted).
To make it a comparative, one says "I like cats better than dogs".
Questions:

Why is "better" used when the non-comparative is "(very) much" whose comparative is normally "more"? Are there historical reasons?
Is it possible to say "I like cats well/good"?


Possible duplicate: "Like something more" or "like something better" https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4988/like-something-more-or-like-something-better#:~:text=To%20increase%20or%20decrease%20the,of%20liking%2C%20not%20its%20intensity.

We can say "I like cats more [than I like dogs]", though "better" is more usual. "I like it well" occurs in Shakespeare and other writers of that time, but is archaic now.

Have you(OP) really never heard someone say "I like X more"? Did someone tell you it was wrong? This question seems based on a misconception, but I'm trying to understand where that misconception came from.

@StuartF At least in English tests, as far as I can remember, I like cats more than dogs would be marked incorrect. In practice, I think I've seen like more but not very often.
